# simple audio engine isBackgroundMusicPlaying is still YES after done playing

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I need to check whether the background music is playing every seconds, and if it's not playing, then i will randomly start to play another song.

This method gets called every seconds

```
- (void)private_checkMusicEnds {

    if (NUM_BGMUSIC > 0) {

        if ([ModuleHelper audio_isBackgroundMusicEnabled]) {
            //ERROR: BACKGROUND MUSIC NOT PLAYING BUT ALWAYS IS PLAYING???



            if ([SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].isBackgroundMusicPlaying == NO) {

                if ([CacheHelper isFirstTimeSetDefaultBGMusic]) {
                    _currentPlayingMusic = DEFAULT_BGMUSIC_INDEX;
                }
                else {
                    //song start at 1
                    _currentPlayingMusic = [Helper getRandomIntBothInclusiveLow:1 high:NUM_BGMUSIC];
                }
                NSString *fn = [NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT_STRING_SONG_FILE_NAME, _currentPlayingMusic];
                [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:fn loop:NO];
            }
        }

    }

}
```

When the song is finished playing, `[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].isBackgroundMusicPlaying` is still YES. 
I have also tried `[[CDAudioManager sharedManager].backgroundMusic isPlaying]` but I get the same.